# How to write the sql command in magento?

Tags: magento

Now, i want to change some products which product's name contains "`legings`" to another category in phpmyadmin. eg:the new category name is `test`. the old category name is `testone` How to write the sql command? thank you.

Comment: do you need a magento way to write it? or you need the query?

Comment: i want to the query. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    $write->query("sqlQuery");
```

### EDIT

Reading the comments your question seems entirely different, I suppose you can do that using Magework. Its a module which allows you to import and export the entire product. Change the Product/Category as you like in the exported file [csv] and then Import it back.

### EDIT

Link [here](http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension) and [Download](http://www.magentoworks.net/import_categories.zip)

Comment: I still didnt understand.. You want to write a SQL query in localhost/phpmyadmin?

Comment: i want to the sql query(put into phpmyadmin sql box) which can update some products to another category?

Comment: you cant just do that.. There are many magento tables which needs to be affected. one product is linked with 5-6 tables depending on magento version.

Comment: if can't is there a way to do this?

Comment: Here's a link to a site (http://www.magereverse.com/) that can help you tease out the many self-joins you will need to execute to do what you think you need to do if you plan on using raw SQL. Magento's EAV system doesn't work the way you are used to using SQL to update standard relational database tables. It is far better to attack this using Magento's collections or the SOAP/WSDL API

Comment: If you're renaming categories, I'd use the Magento model layer to do it.  The database structure is EAV and complex, it's going to be difficult to do it cleanly with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$conn->query("Write your sql query here");
```

In this way you can write plain sql queries in magento.

Thanks.